# highlight tint color unsupported by this button type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am having an issue where I keep getting this warning: `highlight tint color unsupported by this button type`

[image]

I wonder how I remove this warning?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Change the type of your button from Custom to something else.

Comment: Then you'll either have to live with the warning or find another way to do highlight tinting.

Answer (score 15):

My experience is we can just simply set the "Highlight Tint" as "Default" (instead of the default value "Black Color") for each button to remove this warning. :)